# Paypal Express Checkout Authorization Time

Tags: authentication, paypal, express-checkout

I'm doing a paypal Express Checkout operation with SOAP API using the payment action Authorization.
The authorization period is automatically set to 29 days. How can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

The credit card authorization that a bank places on the buyers credit card, is really up to the card issuing bank.  It's not anything you can really change.  The actual hold period can vary slightly as well from one card issuing bank to the next.

Comment: So you're saying that the bank constrint will always override the Paypal setting? Is it correct to consider 29 days as a maximum value for Paypal payments (i.e. no CC involved) and whatever the bank decides for everything else?

Comment: The authorization period time frame within PayPal will not have have any effect on the hold that the card issuing bank places on the funds.  The hold period within PayPal is only within PayPal.  Even though a hold has expired in PayPal, and the transaction can no longer be captured in PayPal, does not mean that there is still not a temp hold on the card issuing bank side.  As for the 29 day time frame, again it depends on the bank.  Most are anywhere from 7 to 29 days.